# How to exclude a specific package from @ControllerAdvice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to know how can we exclude specific package from **@ControllerAdvice**.

That the errors thrown by the classes of that specific package should not be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set @ControllerAdvice to work on specific package via :

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages={"my.pkg.a", "my.pkg.b"})
```

Don't mention the package that you want to ignore.
There is no option for excluding a specific package, but for including is there.